# No Lebesgue-measurable subset such that $\lambda(I\cap A) = \frac{1}{2} \lambda(I) \forall I$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that there exists no Lebesgue-measurable subset $A$ of the real numbers such that for every interval $I$ the Lebesgue measure of $A\cap I$ is half the length of $I$.

My attempt:

assuming there exist such $A$ that works with some interval $I$, I wanted to show that there exists some interval in $I\setminus A$ but I couldn't show it.

Comment: this is easy if you can use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: @KareemMetwaly the set $A$ can have infinite measure?

Comment: @MariosGretsas I think it's possible.

Comment: why this question was marked as a duplicate? The other question is asking a different thing, I dont see the equivalence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume it exists and assume that has finite positive measure.

(If has zero measure then it is obvious that is not true)

Then $\forall \epsilon>0 $,exists a covering    $\{I_n:n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ of $A$ such that $\sum_nm(I_n) \leq m(A)+\epsilon$

Thus $A=\bigcup_n(A \cap I_n)$ and $$m(A) \leq \sum_nm(A \cap I_n)=\sum_n\frac{m(I_n)}{2} \leq \frac{m(A)+\epsilon}{2}$$

Choose $\epsilon =\frac{m(A)}{4}$ and you have a contradiction.

if $A$ has infinite measure and we assume that has the property then  set $A_m=A \cap[-m,m]$ will have the same property so we can restrict ourselves to every subinterval of $[-m,m]$ so by the previous case you can arrive to a contradiction again

Comment: The argument is more complicated when the measure of $A$ is infinity.

Comment: @KaboMurphy if $A$ has infinite measure and we assume that has the property then  set $A_m=A \cap[-m,m]$ will have the same property so we can restrict ourselves to every subinterval of $[-m,m]$...i think