# Instantaneously changing non differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, constructive-mathematics, infinitesimals

Is it possible to construct a function such that it alternates between two values after each "infinitesimal"? Say $0$ and $1$. Now I am not able to properly define the question, but in terms of infinitesimals, what I want is that if $f(x)=0$, then $f(x+dx)=1$ and $f(x+2dx)=0$ and so on. (Maybe someone can help define the problem rigorously too?) 
Like there is a function which is $0$ for rationals and $1$ for irrationals. But it's not exactly alternating in the sense I want. Plus, irrationals are way more dense than rationals, so this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: There are no “infinitesimals” in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @VoiletFlame, yes I know that. That's why I said I couldn't define it rigorously.

Comment: Reminds me of the ito derivative

Comment: I don’t understand, what you want and why, you could let $dx$ be a really small real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "alternating" business is impossible to satisfy since there's no such thing as a "next real number", so I'm going to ignore that part.

But maybe we can fix the irrationals and rationals example by using a set that fills exactly half of each subinterval. Unfortunately, for measure theory reasons typically covered in an upper undergraduate or graduate level real analysis course, even that is impossible. ([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3414503/26369) has a proof and is marked as a duplicate of [this more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103306/26369).)

What about weakening the request even further. Is there a set that takes up half of the interval and is at least kind-of spread out? That's vague, but one thing that comes to mind is the [Smith-Volterra-Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) which is nowhere dense (its set of limit points doesnt contain any interval). Unfortunately, its complement contains a bunch of intervals.

Is there a pair of sets that each take up half of the whole interval $[0,1]$, neither of which contains any intervals and are kind of spread out (so "rationals on the left half, irrationals on the right half" doesn't count)? I don't know, but maybe a version of that is worth asking as a separate question if it interests you. (Note, [we can't require them both to be nowhere dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/224936/26369).)